# Creating a skeleton of part of a web page?

Tags: frontend, mockups

I have been given a requirement to create a layout for a new feature/functionality of a website. I want those reviewing the design to get an idea of both the functionality and feel of how it will look juxtaposed on the existing website. Below is an example of what I am trying to do. I'd appreciate if anyone get me started on this. I don't want to recommendations for tools as much as I want ideas on how would approach this.

[image]

Comment: below where/of what?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to attach the image. It's up now.

Comment: jQuery is not a tool suitable for mock-ups. Instead you might want to consider Balsamiq, Mockingbird, etc. (see also http://mashable.com/2012/06/07/mockup-tools/#hU0yhwa4MSqM).

Comment: There are lots of tools for mockups. Asking for software is off topic for SO though. I suggest you browse through http://alternativeto.net/software/balsamiq-mockups/ or similar sites.

Comment: @TeoMor Maybe, I'm using the word mockups incorrectly. I need to show both look/feel and functionality in the 'mockup'. I believe with Balsamiq I can only get look/feel.

Comment: @bkrsna Ok, then you might want to consider bootstrap css to show how your site will look like. If you go one mile ahead and start using jQuery, then, in my opinion, we cannot talk about mock-ups anymore since you've started to implement the functionality. Of course, you can implement a basic javascript (with jQuery) skeleton for your application. Maybe is a good idea to look for a tutorial about that (https://www.google.ro/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery%20skeleton%20layout). Hope I helped you a little bit.

Comment: @OgnjenBabic why are you removing the embedded image?

Comment: Totally didn't see it..

Comment: @TeoMor Thank you. Those are some good leads for me to get started. I will change the word mockup to a skeleton layout.